# How ngFor in ionic or angular to print different grid system in medium and large screen

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to display grid system from `ngfor` in ionic 3 or angular 4 based on the different screen size for example in below medium`(sm or md)` i need two items per row
 [image: (first image)]

and in large device`(lg or xl)` i need four or more(max 5) items in in single  row [image: like this]

I'm trying like this but it's not working as expected like in `md` and `lg` 3 items in single row and on an item is in centre of the second row but i need two items in single row below `md` and 4 box in in single row in grater than `lg`

```
<ion-grid padding-vertical>
    <ion-row *ngIf="List.length">
      <div *ngFor="let x of List" col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3>     
        <box ....[obj]='x' ></box> <!-- this box tag is custom --> 
      </div>    
    </ion-row>   

  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: how is it showing for the code? also suggest using `ion-col` instead of `div`

Comment: showing 3 items in one row 4th items in second row in centre at > md and < lg devices screen but i need differently my box as some fixed width and height